# Is it safe to delete Kafka/log old file?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have Kafka server instance in my cloud server, consist of 3 brokers 3 zk and 12 connect workers. As we know, Kafka main folder are consist of bin,config,and logs. I want to ask if i want to safe the disk size, is it safe to delete old server.log, connect.log and zookeeper_gc.log file in logs folder? And if it yes, then how i delete/compress it periodically (for example every day or week)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question, Yes it is ok to delete old Kafka log files. Those are meant for your use only if you want to trace back the history logs.

For the second one, you can check the log4j properties file under /config folder. By default Kafka provides DailyRollingAppender which you can change to RollingAppender of your liking..

Snippets from default kafka log4j properties. Ref https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

You can potentially update the RollingAppender like below which will keep maximum 10 files of 25MB each so never occupying more than 250MB.

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxFileSize=25MB
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

Please note there are several appender in the above log properties file (ref above link), you got to update settings for each of those accordingly.

Comment: To add a sidenote, you will need to restart Kafka brokers to pick those updates.

Comment: Great... pleased to be of help!

Comment: but i have another problem. I want to do this config also for zookeeper and kafka-connect. When i try to manually delete all the dump file with regex *.log.*, suddenly after i restart kafka, i cannot restart my kafka connect

Comment: Zookeeper also has a similar file... You may find these useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691341/zookeeper-log-file-not-created-inside-logs-directory
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612908/why-does-zookeeper-not-use-my-log4j-properties-file-log-directory

Answer (score 0):

Kafka uses **log.cleanup.policy** configuration property to define cleanup strategies. Furthermore, it uses **log.retention.check.interval.ms** configuration property as the interval between regular log checks. So the above two properties will allow one to cleanup old logs at required intervals.

Here are further details for your reference: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-log-cleanup-policies.html

Comment: Thank you @khasim-umer, but I have set it for my kafka log folder, and what i talk about its logs folder inside kafka main folder, side by side with bin folder and config folder.